# Why does this set of polygons cause CGAL::join to crash?

Tags: cgal, polygons

Using CGAL 4.5.2. Below sample causes a bunch of precondition violations, followed by an access violation exception. The funny thing is that if you remove any of the 6 polygons from the input, everything runs fine. Why is this happening?

The only unusual thing about the polygons that I can see is that poly6 has a duplicate point - but it is not self-intersecting, only touching, so I believe this shouldn't be a problem? And as said above, when you remove any of the other polygons, this polygon can be handled just fine.

Is something wrong with my input? Or is there some other problem?

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Knl; 
typedef CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2<Knl> Polygon_with_holes; 
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Knl> Polygon; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
    std::list<Polygon> polys; 

    Polygon poly1; 
    poly1.push_back(Point_2(417340.5, 523797.5)); 
    poly1.push_back(Point_2(419348.3269736591, 508552.92065337556)); 
    poly1.push_back(Point_2(421866.5, 489433.5)); 
    poly1.push_back(Point_2(421865.5, 489447.5)); 
    poly1.push_back(Point_2(417342.43500051671, 523783.40213909268)); 
    poly1.push_back(Point_2(417341.5, 523790.5)); 
    polys.push_back(poly1); 

    Polygon poly2; 
    poly2.push_back(Point_2(417342.43500051671, 523783.40213909268)); 
    poly2.push_back(Point_2(421865.5, 489447.5)); 
    poly2.push_back(Point_2(421837.5, 489724.5)); 
    poly2.push_back(Point_2(417365.15018218826, 523612.759577192)); 
    poly2.push_back(Point_2(417347.5, 523746.5)); 
    poly2.push_back(Point_2(417346.5, 523753.5)); 
    poly2.push_back(Point_2(417344, 523772)); 
    poly2.push_back(Point_2(417342.74397163116, 523781.15106382978)); 
    polys.push_back(poly2); 

    Polygon poly3; 
    poly3.push_back(Point_2(421837.5, 489724.5)); 
    poly3.push_back(Point_2(421832.5, 489771.5)); 
    poly3.push_back(Point_2(421831.5, 489780.5)); 
    poly3.push_back(Point_2(417365.84675276978, 523607.52457525046)); 
    polys.push_back(poly3); 

    Polygon poly4; 
    poly4.push_back(Point_2(421831.5, 489780.5)); 
    poly4.push_back(Point_2(421830.5, 489794.5)); 
    poly4.push_back(Point_2(417366.29927861993, 523604.12366546877)); 
    polys.push_back(poly4); 

    Polygon poly5; 
    poly5.push_back(Point_2(417322.5, 523931.5)); 
    poly5.push_back(Point_2(417318.5, 523966.5)); 
    poly5.push_back(Point_2(417317.5, 523968.5)); 
    polys.push_back(poly5); 

    Polygon poly6; 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417344, 523772)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417346.5, 523753.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417346.72222222225, 523752.16666666663)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417347.5, 523746.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417366.29927861993, 523604.12366546877)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(421830.5, 489794.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(421802.5, 490071.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417411.35391183395, 523265.52037297864)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417359.5, 523657.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417358.5, 523664.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417355.28571428568, 523688.92857142852)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417353.5, 523702.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417352.5, 523709.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417347.5, 523746.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417347.5, 523747.5)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417346.72222222225, 523752.16666666663)); 
    poly6.push_back(Point_2(417346.33333333337, 523755)); 
    polys.push_back(poly6); 

    list<Polygon_with_holes> polyHoles; 
    CGAL::join(polys.begin(), polys.end(), std::back_inserter(polyHoles)); 
}
```